# move_uploaded_file() Isn't uploading files

Tags: php, upload

I a php script which is called from a file form and it is supposed to check the form for password, filename, filetype and errors uploading to temp. If it passes all tests it's supposed to upload using `move_uploaded_file` but this does not work. No errors are outputted but I know it passes all the tests otherwise it would return back to the page.
PHP script:

```
<?php
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
if ($_POST["pass"] == "examplePass"){
    if($_FILES["file"]["name"] == ""){
        header("Location: /upload?i=f");
    }
    elseif($_FILES["file"]["type"] != "application/x-shockwave-flash"){
        header("Location: /upload?i=s");
    }
    elseif ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        header("Location: /upload?i=e");
    }
    else{
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/swf/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        if(file_exists("/swf/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            header("Location: /upload?i=o");
        }
        else{
            print_r($_FILES);
        }       
    }
}
else{
    header("Location: /upload?i=p");
}
?>
```

This outputs:

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => launcher.swf [type] => application/x-shockwave-flash [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpBugtQL [error] => 0 [size] => 161303 ) )
```

I have tried this with multiple swf files and I can remember it used to work.
I have set the whole of my web folder to 0777 and also recursed this into all sub-directories and files.
The directory /swf/ is at root so that is the absolute path.
Thanks in advance, Kyle

Comment: Does your form use the encoding multipart/form-data? Try to open a file handler and write a file in the dir. Whats the return value of move_uploaded_file?

Comment: For debug purposes, have you tried `move_uploaded_file` to the same directory as the script?

Comment: Yeah my encoding is correct, and I'll try that Lasse

Comment: Uploading to the same directory does work, what does this mean then?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using, `../swf/` or full path of the swf folder instead of `/swf/`

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../swf/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Reason for `swf` folder path, make sure you have used the correct path

Comment: Like I said, swf is in the root folder of my web server so the full path to it from the web is: serverurl/swf/ <-- this brings up the directory on my server, also I thought you're not supposed to use relative file paths with move_uploaded_file as it has unexpected results

Comment: I tried putting my php script on the root and it worked and then when I moved it back it worked again :/ thanks anyway